# Find all documents which have certain element is not undefined with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is a Event model:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var Event = new Schema({
        eventname: String,
        location: String,
        note: String,
        remind: String,
        userid: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        projectid: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', Event);
```

If event belongs to a project it will save the id of project in projectid, if not projectid will be undefined.

I wonder how to find all the documents which have projectid is not undefined with mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Query#exists`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exists) for that:

```
Event.where('projectid').exists().exec(function(err, docs) {
  ...
});
```